# Can't get content on the same row

Tags: html, css

Ive been working on this menu and I can't get my parts of my menu to display within the same row. So far I've been going off how to nest rows under bootstrap's website. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance! This is what I have so far:

```html
<div class="row">    
        <div class="menu container-fluid">   
            <div class="row">
                <div class="dropdownn col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="espressoDrinks" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Espresso Drinks
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="espressoDrinks">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Espresso</li>
                                <p>2 oz. 4 oz. or 6 oz. of the finest pure espresso</p>
                            <li>Americano</li>
                                <p>Fresh brewed  espresso with hot water</p>
                            <li>Macchiato</li>
                                <p>Espresso with a dallop of foam</p>
                            <li>Cappuccino</li>
                             <p>Espresso with steamed milk, topped with a crown of foam</p>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
            </div>    
              
           <!-- </div>  -->
            <div class="row">   
                <div class="dropdown col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="blendedEspresso" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Blended Espresso Shakes
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="blendedEspresso">    
                        <ul>
                            <li>Blended Bliss</li>
                                <p>Espresso, chocolate and lowfat ice milk blended into a refreshing shake, topped with whipped cream. Delicious!</p>
                            <li>Java Chill</li>
                                <p>Brewed espresso blended with lowfat ice milk, a splash of a flavor of your choosing, and topped with whipped cream</p>
                            <li> White Mocha Chill</li>
                                <p>Blended Ghirardelli white chocolate mocha capped with whipped cream</p>
                            <li>Malty-Malt</li>
                                <p>Blended chocolate mocha with malted milk and topped with whipped cream</p>
                            <li>Minty-Mint</li>
                                <p>Blended mocha spun with a whole peppermint patty and topped with cream</p>
                        </ul>   
                  </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the .row classes are meant to organize the nested and/ or .col-xxx classes. Therefore  all your .rows must be placed in  one .container 
Then if you want to organize content in .rows you have to place your contents in .col-xxx.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=".col-md-6"></div><div class=".col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class=".col-md-6"></div><div class=".col-md-6"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```